# VS Code Extension - How to add a WebviewPanel to the sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, view, vscode-extensions

According to [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) webviews can be "rendered in the sidebar or panel areas". The examples show how to render as editor panels...

```ts
vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
    'catCoding', // Identifies the type of the webview. Used internally
    'Cat Coding', // Title of the panel displayed to the user
    vscode.ViewColumn.One, // Editor column to show the new webview panel in.
    {} // Webview options..
);
```

I'm trying to render the webview as an additional panel in the sidebar under explorer.

I'm assuming some kind of change to the 3rd arg `vscode.ViewColumn.One`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Gamma11, thanks for your answer.  Definitely helped resolve the "labyrinth of definitions"

Elaborating that out a bit (and maybe simplifying/clarifying the [webview-view-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-view-sample/src/extension.ts) with a tighter JS (as opposed to TS) version):

1 - In package.json you have the following entry defining the view as a webview that lives in the sidebar explorer:

```
"views": {
    "explorer": [
        {
            "type": "webview",
            "id": "calicoColors.colorsView",
            "name": "Trillion Files"
        }
    ]
}
```

2 - Also in package.json the activation that sends to JS

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onView:calicoColors.colorsView"
]
```

3 - In JS the event is picked up by vscode.commands.registerCommand

```
function activate(context){
    var thisProvider={
        resolveWebviewView:function(thisWebview, thisWebviewContext, thisToken){
            thisWebviewView.webview.options={enableScripts:true}
            thisWebviewView.webview.html="<!doctype><html>[etc etc]";
        }
    };
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerWebviewViewProvider("calicoColors.colorView", thisProvider);
    );
}

function deactivate() { }

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

There are plenty more properties that can go into thisProvider, but this minimal code gets a panel up and running in the sidebar.

Answer (score 11):

It seems like [`createWebviewPanel()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createWebviewPanel) is actually *only* for webviews shown in the editor. For the side bar, you have to use [`registerWebviewViewProvider()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.registerWebviewViewProvider) as shown in the [`webview-view-sample`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-view-sample/src/extension.ts) linked on that page:

```ts
vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider('calicoColors.colorsView', provider));
```

And then specify which view to show it in via `package.json` - the example uses the Explorer:

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "views": {
            "explorer": [
                {
                    "type": "webview",
                    "id": "calicoColors.colorsView",
                    "name": "Calico Colors"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far, navigating the example code and API docs, it seems more like a labyrinth of circular definitions.  You need to register a WebviewViewProvider, which in turn involves a WebviewViewProvider which in turn involves a WebviewView, which in turn involves a Webview.  Haven't been able to glean which of those can or must be defined in the JS context, and which perhaps inherit their value from the the package.json.

Answer (score -1):

use *vscode.ViewColumn.Beside* for show on the side bar

this is how viewColumn is used

```
export enum ViewColumn {
        /**
         * A *symbolic* editor column representing the currently active column. This value
         * can be used when opening editors, but the *resolved* {@link TextEditor.viewColumn viewColumn}-value
         * of editors will always be `One`, `Two`, `Three`,... or `undefined` but never `Active`.
         */
        Active = -1,
        /**
         * A *symbolic* editor column representing the column to the side of the active one. This value
         * can be used when opening editors, but the *resolved* {@link TextEditor.viewColumn viewColumn}-value
         * of editors will always be `One`, `Two`, `Three`,... or `undefined` but never `Beside`.
         */
        Beside = -2,
        /**
         * The first editor column.
         */
        One = 1,
        /**
         * The second editor column.
         */
        Two = 2,
        /**
         * The third editor column.
         */
        Three = 3,
        /**
         * The fourth editor column.
         */
        Four = 4,
        /**
         * The fifth editor column.
         */
        Five = 5,
        /**
         * The sixth editor column.
         */
        Six = 6,
        /**
         * The seventh editor column.
         */
        Seven = 7,
        /**
         * The eighth editor column.
         */
        Eight = 8,
        /**
         * The ninth editor column.
         */
        Nine = 9
    }
```

Comment: It's great that you're giving a detailed explanation of the enum governing position, but could you expand on this a bit to show how this would go into defining a WebviewPanel config? It would be a more complete answer and help illustrate specifically how this is done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 'vscode.ViewColumn.Beside' is not for the side bar, but the edit column beside the active one.