# Better formatted tree view items with VSCode API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I want to create tree view items like these, similarly to the ones you see here with Thunder Client extension, unfortunately, they do not have their source code public. Is there any way to go about this using the VSCode API to tap into creating more sophisticated items.

[image]

Comment: just download the extension and unzip, create a `Webviewview`, you have total control of the HTML/CSS

Comment: they have webpacked the whole lot, so reformat the code and try to find the `activate` function

Comment: Hey @rioV8 I have downloaded the extension into VSCode, how do i go about unzipping it? as for making a webview, I only really need a minimal treeview like the one Thunder Client has without implementing a full webview for it

Comment: you have the option of a list tree like Explorer, otherwise you have to make thing yourself from scratch or use some HTML GUI lib in a WebviewView, if you download the VSIX file, use an unzip tool, VSIX === Zip, or look in your extensions directory for the Thunder extension (look for full name)

Comment: Oh okay, I did not know I had the option to make a list tree like an Explorer, how do i go about this? I will be looking into the unzipped version of thunder client now. What do you mean by WebviewView, isn't it just Webview?

Comment: you can't make something like the Thunder List with a TreeView, see the VSC extension doc on TreeView

Comment: That's odd, because Thunder Client made it, and I don't think they have any more access to the VSCode API than I do, as for going through their extension, their code is jumbled up and minifed, I'm not sure how to move forward :(

Comment: I just found out that Thunder Client is rendering a HTML into the tree view like a webview, how is this possible?

Comment: see my first comment

Comment: I see, the answer for my question then is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150547/vs-code-extension-how-to-add-a-webviewpanel-to-the-sidebar