# VS Code Extension Sidepanel Webview Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make a webview in the sidepanel for a VS Code extension. I have checked this stackoverflow answer [VS Code Extension - How to add a WebviewPanel to the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150547/vs-code-extension-how-to-add-a-webviewpanel-to-the-sidebar) and have also reviewed the sample code https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-view-sample/src/extension.ts . However the sidepanel is unable to load any data. Here is my code:

extension.js

```
vscode = require("vscode");
path = require("path")


/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */

function activate(context) {
    let diagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics();
    console.log(diagnostics)
    console.log("adrenaline has started")
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "bugfixer" is now active!');
    (async () => {

        })();
    const panel = (
        'adrenaline',
        'Adrenaline',
        vscode.ViewColumn.One,
        {// Enable scripts in the webview
            enableScripts: true}
      );
      var thisProvider={
        resolveWebviewView:function(thisWebview, thisWebviewContext, thisToken){
            thisWebviewView.webview.options={enableScripts:true}
            thisWebviewView.webview.html="<html>hello</html>";
        }
    };
      // And set its HTML content
      panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
      panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(
        message => {
          switch (message.command) {
            case 'alert':
              vscode.window.showErrorMessage(message.text);
              return;
          }
        },
        undefined,
        context.subscriptions
      );
    context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerWebviewViewProvider('adrenaline.start', thisProvider
    )
  );
   
}
function getWebviewContent() {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>hello</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "adrenaline",
  "displayName": "adrenaline",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.74.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView: adrenaline.start"    
  ],
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "views": {
      "explorer": [
          {
              "type": "webview",
              "id": "adrenaline.start",
              "name": "Adrenaline"
          }
      ]
  },
    "commands": [{
      "command": "adrenaline.start",
      "title": "adrenaline"
    }]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "node ./test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.74.0",
    "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "views": {
    "explorer": [
        {
            "type": "webview",
            "id": "adrenaline.start",
            "name": "Adrenaline"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I have tried using "panel" and "thisProvider". VS Code returns the error `Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.adrenaline' failed: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'html').` and just shows the sidepanel as loading
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6aqg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain exactly what you're trying to run with your source code, but here's a cleaned up version that produces a webview and a matching command, at least.

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */

function activate(context) {
  console.log("adrenaline has started");

  const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
    'adrenaline',
    'Adrenaline',
    vscode.ViewColumn.One,
    {// Enable scripts in the webview
        enableScripts: true
    }
  );

  const thisProvider = {
    resolveWebviewView:function(thisWebviewView, thisWebviewContext, thisToken){
        thisWebviewView.webview.options={enableScripts:true};
        thisWebviewView.webview.html="<html>hello</html>";
    },
    sayHi:function() { console.log("hi"); }
  };

  // And set its HTML content
  panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
  panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(
    message => {
      switch (message.command) {
      case 'alert':
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage(message.text);
        return;
      }
    },
    undefined,
    context.subscriptions
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider('adrenaline.webview', thisProvider
    )
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('adrenaline.start', function () {thisProvider.sayHi();})
  );
}

function getWebviewContent() {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>hello again!</html>`;
}

module.exports = {
  activate
};
```